# Imperative + (the +) next

Tags: grammaticality, articles

At a certain point of a document that I am writing, I need to refer the reader to the next section in the following way: "(see **the** next section)". My question is: do I have to omit the **the** or is it fine like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal speech (or writing) it requires "the".

But in the abbreviated English often used for written instructions it can be omitted.

So both are acceptable: omitting "the" makes it sound a little detached and impersonal - perhaps officious; including "the" makes it a little more friendly and natural.